Website scrolls to bottom onload on mobile
I made an weather app that fetched data from API. When I visit it on my mobile the website waits for data and then displays but it also is scrolled to the bottom not the top
I tried
window.onload = () => { setTimeout(() => { window.scrollTo(0, 0); }, 100);
After my data fetches

source code: https://github.com/MevWebDev/weather-app

link: mev.pxseu.com/weather-app
